# How to make time slots using kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, development-environment

```
"StartingTime":"11:00",
"EndingTime":"5:00"
```

Hello,i have a JSON response in which i have these two strings.What i want to do is I want to make time slots using these startingTime and EndingTime.BTW,these two can change for different responses.I want to make time slots with 2 hrs difference between them.Also I want to add an extra 2 hour after the EndingTime.

Example:
Startime = 11:00
EndingTime = 5:00

Time Slots I need = 11:00-1:00 , 1:00-3:00 , 3:00-5:00 , 5:00-7:00

Also once I get this time slots I want to store and add them in a spinner.
How can I achieve it.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a simple data class to represent a time slot.

```
data class TimeSlot(val startTime: LocalTime, val endTime: LocalTime)
```

And then write a function that splits it up into as many slots that will fit:

```
fun TimeSlot.divide(lengthHours: Long): List<TimeSlot> {
    require(lengthHours > 0) { "lengthHours was $lengthHours. Must specify positive amount of hours."}
    val timeSlots = mutableListOf<TimeSlot>()
    var nextStartTime = startTime
    while (true) {
        val nextEndTime = nextStartTime.plusHours(lengthHours)
        if (nextEndTime > endTime) {
            break
        }
        timeSlots.add(TimeSlot(nextStartTime, nextEndTime))
        nextStartTime = nextEndTime
    }
    return timeSlots
}
```

Note, this simple comparison `nextEndTime > endTime` won't handle a time range that crosses midnight. You'd have to make this a little more complicated if you want to handle that.

You can look up in other existing questions how to parse the JSON values into LocalTimes and how to populate a Spinner from a List.

Comment: What should be the lengthHours to be passed if the slot interval needed is half an hour ?

Comment: You can change the parameter type to mean minutes and use `plusMinutes` instead of `plusHours`.

Comment: Great man , missed on that one . Thanks